# Библиотека для SteamAPI

Tags: steam

Есть библиотека [steampy](https://github.com/bukson/steampy) которая работает, но для авторизации в стиме методом login требуется создавать в директории проекта файл Steamguard.txt с "shared_secret" и "identity_secret" которые нужны вытащить из маФайла стимгварда. Без этих переменных авторизация и дальнейшая работа с библиотекой невозможна. Настал вопрос, возможно переписать метод авторизации так, чтоб он не использовал этот стимгвард для создания временного ключа собственно с помощью которого он и авторизируется сам, а запрашивал код у пользователя, после ввода которого происходила авторизация? Так как опыта у меня такого мало, может ли кто переписать авторизацию в этой библиотеке?
Или есть аналогичные библиотеки, где не требуется файл со стимгвардом?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Скорее всего можно такое сделать, но будет сложновато, так как на момент 21 января 2024 есть пару проблем с аутентификацией.

Comment: проблемы с аутентификацией были решены https://github.com/bukson/steampy/pull/344/commits/9a44751385e99f871833ed2742d791bae403bf17